# How to add ahci module to linux-image-2.6.38-11-virtual kernel?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, ubuntu-11.04, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I just installed Ubuntu 11.04 with the `linux-image-2.6.38-11-virtual` kernel as a virtual machine in VirtualBox (4.1.2). When I booted the machine after installation, I got this error message:

```
FATAL: Error inserting ahci (/lib/modules/2.6.38-11-virtual/kernel/drivers/ata/ahci.
ko): Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)
```

I found [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/570542).  In prior Ubuntu releases, the virtual linux kernel did not include the ahci module, which I suspect is causing my problem. Could someone confirm my suspicion and tell me how to correct the error? I'm a bit new to linux, so thorough detail would be helpful.

Here is a capture of my dmesg output:

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't virtualbox be using the virtual disk interface ( /dev/vda ), instead of pretending to have an AHCI interface?  Also it suggests checking dmesg for more details, so what does it say?

Comment: @psusi - I have several other Ubuntu installations in Virtualbox using /dev/sda, and they work without a problem. As for dmesg--it's hundreds of lines long, and I can get the contents of it. The basic terminal that loads uses rootfs as / (I assume a virtual file system), and it does not have ftp, less, gpated, fdisk, or apt-get. Unless you can tell me a way to copy the dmesg contents, I cannot provide them to you.

Comment: only the last few lines are likely to matter.  Take a look at them and just retype them by hand if you need to.  You should be able to spot the one or two lines that relate to the ahci module failing to load.

Comment: @psusi - see the link I added under edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that libahci.ko ( on which ahci depends ) is missing from the -virtual kernel package.  This is a bug.

Comment: That's what I suspected.  How do I fix it?

Comment: @BrandonLebedev, report the bug to Ubuntu.

Comment: Bug report [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/658461).